# Reloading navigation properties after detaching a new object

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, poco

I am using Entity Framework with POCO objects and have the following scenario:

I create a new parent object and add a child object to it. Then I save changes and detach the parent object. At this moment its children collection gets empty.

```
parent = new Parent() { label = "Test" };
parent.Children.Add(new Child() { label = "Test" });
context.Parents.AddObject(parent);
context.SaveChanges();
context.Detach(parent);
```

When I reattach the parent object to a different context, I have to explicitly load the corresponding property to access the children collection.

```
context.Parents.Attach(parent);
context.LoadProperty(parent, p => p.Children);
```

Is there any way for the navigation properties to lazy load instead of having to load manually every one of them?

If instead of creating a new object, I retrieve an existing object, the problem does not occur: the children collection gets empty when detached; but after reattaching, the children are lazy loaded automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
parent = new Parent() { label = "Test" };
```

Try to use:

```
parent = context.CreateObject<Parent>();
parent.label = "Test";
```

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka Works like a charm, thanks. Are there other cases where CreateObject<T> is required for proper operation instead of new?

Comment: @Damir - `CreateObject` creates proxied instance of `Parent`. Proxy is needed for lazy loading or one way to do change tracking.