# Linq to Entity - what's the best method of determining the number of entitysets from entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have an entity returned detached from bizlogic.

I now want to check how many entitysets there are in a many to many relationship.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
context.Attach(entity);
entity.entityset.Load();
int count entity.entityset.count();
```

There is more to this simple example but for now I just want to know how I can extract the number of entitysets in the most efficient way possible. The above example gives me the impression I am loading the whole list of entityset records before determining the number of records, unless I've misunderstood the fundamentals of Linq to Entity. (I'm new to this and from Net Tiers)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the navigation property directly, then `Count()` should be turned into this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value]
FROM [entityset] AS [t0]
```

I don't know for sure, but I also get the impression that `Load()` will load the whole set into memory first.  So try not doing that :)

*Edit:* [This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472254/reloading-navigation-properties-after-detaching-a-new-object), in that they are re-attaching entities, and then trying to get navigation properties to work correctly.  It might be applicable.

Comment: I have tried to avoid the Load at all costs but there is no other way round this. Sorry not sure what you mean by navigation property, is that the entity.entityset (entityset is the navigation property)? Need to load that first to work otherwise always zero count. (Still new to Linq to Entities)

Comment: @Rob: Yep, that's the navigation property.  Can you rewrite your query this way `context.EntitySet.Where(es => es.EntityId == entity.Id).Count()`?  You might also try to apply the answer to this question to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472254/reloading-navigation-properties-after-detaching-a-new-object

Comment: Not sure if 5472254 is helpful, sorry. I cannot see context.EntitySet? I only see context.Entity and context.Entity.EntitySet.

Comment: @Rob: The query I gave you isn't from that link, it's a separate option.  Though that's weird - all entities should be visible in sets directly from the context, unless you have a "complex type" that isn't itself mapped to an entity in your model, in which case you can just map it as an entity.  As for the question I linked, I'm thinking `context.CreateObject<Entity>();`, add the appropriate key properties, then query `entity.EntitySet`.  Or simply re-query: `context.Entities.Single(e => e.Id == entity.Id).EntitySet.Count()`.

Comment: I used the default method of updating from database into edmx!?!? :)(Still learning) I see what you're saying and sounds good. Will attempt this later and let you know. Didn't think of "context.Entities.Single(e => e.Id == entity.Id).EntitySet.Count()". I need to understand the "context.CreateObject<Entity>();" before applying this to my code. Thanks for your help.